# The Parse current user is not deleted after app reinstalled

Tags: android, parse-android-sdk

Users reported to us that they uninstalled the app, then reinstalled it and they were immediately transferred to the Home screen, instead of the Login screen. The thing is, since they don't login they don't have a Session token and hence, they can't call cloud functions!

Here's my check:

```
if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser()==null) {
    // show login screen
}
else {
    // show home screen
}
```

Here's an email we just got

> I have managed to fix the problem. I had to clear all my temporary data for the application and reinstall it. After that it worked like it should. So the problem was with some temporary saved data in my device.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AndroidManifest` under the `application` tag, there is an `android:allowBackup`
flag that was responsible for this. as the documentation said:

> android:allowBackup Whether to allow the application to participate in
>   the backup and restore infrastructure. If this attribute is set to
>   false, no backup or restore of the application will ever be performed,
>   even by a full-system backup that would otherwise cause all
>   application data to be saved via adb. The default value of this
>   attribute is true.

For your problem, you must make this `false`.